# SQL Server stored procedure NATIVE_COMPILATION IsNumeric() alternative?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm converting a stored procedure to a native_compilation stored procedure and I ran into `ISNUMERIC()` not being supported.

Is there any work around to achieve the same result of checking if a column is a numeric value that works with native compiled stored procedures? I tried `TRYPARSE()` but that also is not supported.

Comment: Are you trying to validate that the value is an integer, a numeric with decimals, or all of the same things isnumeric() allows (which is a lot more than just integers and decimals)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand integers and decimals would be sufficient for my situation

Comment: If the stored procedure needs to do things that native compilation doesn't support, I wonder if native compilation will actually help. Have you profiled and compared traditional and native compilation procedures that do the things they're doing *without* the unsupported functions? You might need to resort to interop in which case any performance benefits (if there even are any; native compilation helps certain workloads but isn't magic) are likely to be offset.